# Reference for shloka - Yathā nāma rūpā vimuktā samudre saṅga gacchant

Tags: vedas, puranas, mantras, reference-request, shloka

which scripture does this shloka belongs to:

> Yathā nāma rūpā vimuktā samudre saṅga gacchant

> यथा नाम रूपा विमुक्ता समुद्रे संग गच्छन्ति

based on the verse it sounds like its related to Kaivalya mukti roughly translating to like the flowing river merges into ocean similarly liberated souls merges into god.